# Is there a way to compile LESS files to CSS (so that every browser doesn't have to)?

Tags: css, css-framework

I'm considering using [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) but I cringe at the thought of a browser having JavaScript disabled and my CSS not being readable (and the site looking awful).

Also, it offends the engineer in me to force every browser to "compile" that Less file to .css when we could just "compile" it once every-time we modify it.

Comment: @Anonymous- If you check out LESS, you should also have a look at SASS and COMPASS.

Comment: Stylus and OOCSS are also similar products.

Comment: I have posted a related answer explaining how to set up LESS compilation automatically on the server: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/38386/how-to-automatically-compile-less-into-css-on-the-server/38387#38387

Comment: I didn't know anyone was compiling LESS in browsers!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. You can use an app that auto-compiles LESS files to CSS on your development machine as you code. Then simply upload the generated CSS file to your server when you're done developing.

- [Crunch!](http://crunchapp.net/) for Windows & Mac
- [WinLess](http://winless.org/) for Windows
- [CodeKit](http://incident57.com/codekit/) for Mac

Answer (score 11):

I use [SimpLESS](http://wearekiss.com/simpless) - drag, drop, done.

Answer (score 10):

LESS comes with a binary (lessc) that lets you precompile your .less files. You use it as such:

```
 $ lessc styles.less > styles.css
```

<s>But I think most people just use the `lessc -w` or `lessc --watch` command to recompile the CSS stylesheet automatically whenever the LESS file is updated. You can also have lessc minify the CSS, e.g. `lessc -w -x`.</s>

**Edit:** Just to clarify, lessc comes with the server-side install (i.e. when you install less via the node.js package manager). But you can [download it manually from GitHub](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/downloads).

lessc is located at `/bin/lessc`. This is of course a *nix binary (should also work for Mac), but there *is* a Windows binary ([lessc.exe](http://digitalpbk.com/less-css/less-css-compiler-windows-lesscexe)) based on dotless, which is another Windows LESS compiler.

**Update:**
Use [`less-watch`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/less-watch) to automatically compile.

Alternatively, many developers these days use task runners like [`grunt`](http://gruntjs.com/) to handle build automation (compiling, minify, testing, etc.). Using `grunt-contrib-watch`, `grunt-contrib-less` and `grunt-contrib-livereload`, you can really streamline your development workflow.

E.g. if you use [`yo`](http://yeoman.io/) to scaffold your new web project, it comes preconfigured to watch your LESS/CSS/JS/HTML files for changes and recompile the necessary parts of your project when needed. Simply run `grunt serve`, and you're ready to code without having to worry about manually compiling (LESS/SASS/CoffeeScript)/minifying/concatenating your code or refreshing your browser manually like a caveman...

Comment: I'm not sure what version you're using. In the latest version 1.3.0 there is no --watch feature. A pull request for a --watch feature was shot down 9 months ago. https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/pull/246

Comment: @BullfrogBlues: Sorry, that was from the old Ruby-based lessc.

Comment: Note: "less-watch has been renamed to fs-change. Use that instead: `npm install -g fs-change`."

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of options for compiling LESS to CSS on the server, and the one you choose will probably depend on what you use for the rest of the site.

- If you use node.js, the original [lesscss](http://lesscss.org/) will do the job.
- If you use PHP, [lessphp](http://leafo.net/lessphp/). It has a slightly rubbish API when it comes to passing variables in from PHP, but it does the job.
- If you use Ruby, [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) isn't LESS, but is so similar that when I switched from using SASS (personal project) to LESS (a PHP project at work) I didn't notice any differences other than the file extension. It also has a useful library of mixins - [COMPASS](http://compass-style.org/). I haven't tried using them with LESS, but I expect they'd work. (Apparently LESS was originally Ruby, so there's probably an old compiler floating around somewhere too).
- If you use ASP.Net, there's [.less](http://www.dotlesscss.org/). I haven't used this one, so I don't know how well it works.
- If you use Java, [lesscss4j](http://code.google.com/p/lesscss4j/) wraps up compiling with the original LESS and Java 6's built-in Rhino scripting environment.
- If you use Perl, there's a [LESSp](http://search.cpan.org/~drinchev/CSS-LESSp-0.86/lib/CSS/LESSp.pm) module in CPAN.

Comment: There _is_ a Ruby compiler that comes with the old LESS Ruby gem but it's not updated anymore so a lot of the new features won't work on it. Thus, if you use Ruby, I would recommend just using the `lessc` binary compiler that is based off of the latest version of less.js.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté, I'd just go with SASS, but I didn't want to be accused of wilfully ignoring the possibility of compiling LESS in Ruby.

Comment: Yea, I think SASS would be the best option for Ruby since the LESS gem has been deprecated since the switch to JS.

Comment: In addition to this (excellent!) list, I think https://github.com/lesscpy/lesscpy is worth mentioning. It uses Python, can be installed through pip, and supports many interesting features. Also, it has been updated regularly (last update was 7 months ago), as opposed to some of the options you list.